# How to Pass Multipart File from one Method to Another in Controller

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Can anyone help me how can i pass RequestParam Multipart file from one method to another in Controller.

From JSP I am taking 3 inputs, 1 of them I will required later on clicking of a different button I want that file for modification.
So I have Created 2 methods in Controller - one - which is Accepting 3 RequestParam and which will work with 2 RequestParam, and another method will be trigger on clicking of a another button in which I want to access the 3rd RequestParam which is a MultiPartFile.

I tried to store this MultiPartFile in ClassLevel Variable , but getting error like file not found while using it in another method.
also I have tried to get the Inputstream out of it and store it in a classlevel variable, this is working fine but Once read the InputStream it's closed right, we can't use that again in the same session, if i click on the button again it will throw error.

SO I want a way to pass that file in the different controller method so that I can get InputStream from it how many time i will click in the button.

Here is the controller :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public String handleForm(@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("pass") String pass, @RequestParam("file")MultipartFile excelFile, Model model) {
        try {
            ------
}
}

@GetMapping(value = "/processFile")
    public void processFile() {
        try {
         ---
}
}
```

So here in handleForm i am getting the file - excelFile, I want to use that in processFile method, but i can't call that method in handleForm() method because processFile() method to be called in separate button click

Comment: You don't pass around multipart files because that's mostly an upload mechanism. Once you uploaded it, store the file as a `File` object somewhere on your server or put the binary content (a byte array) into a database. Then return some information to the client where to find that file, e.g. a relative path or a record id. When pressing the button the client then sends this piece of information to your second method which can use it to retrieve the file/byte array.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Provide the path to store the Excel file
// A better way is to not hardcode the file name
final static String fileLocation = "/path/to/save/your-excel-file.xlsx";

@PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public String handleForm(
        @RequestParam("email") String email, 
        @RequestParam("pass") String pass,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile excelFile,
        Model model) {

    //save uploaded file to given location
    saveMultipartFile(excelFile);
}

//It would be nice to change this, the name of the uploaded file can be redirected to download and that file can be downloaded
@GetMapping(value = "/processFile")
public ResponseEntity<?> processFile() {
    
    //convert file to org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
    Resource resource = null;
    try {
        resource = new UrlResource(Paths.get(fileLocation).toUri());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().build();
    }

    String contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    String headerValue = "attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + "\"";

    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, headerValue)
            .body(resource);
}

/**
 * Save uploaded MultipartFile to the given location
 * @param file
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void saveMultipartFile(MultipartFile file)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

    Path targetLocation = Paths.get(fileLocation);

    // Creates a directory by creating all nonexistent parent directories first.
    Files.createDirectories(targetLocation.getParent());

    // Writes bytes to a file for the given target location.
    Files.write(targetLocation, bytes);
}
```